# Is handling requests/accessing database in views a good practice?

Tags: django, django-views

I have a problem with django's MVC. I understand that this is not the traditional MVC, but the documentation emphasizes throughout that it indeed separates presentation from business logic. However, the tutorial comes to a piece of code like this:

```
def vote(request, poll_id):
    p = get_object_or_404(Poll, id=poll_id)    

    try:
        selected_choice = p.choice_set.get(id=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):   
        return render_to_response('polls/detail.html', 
                                  { 'poll': p, 'error_message': 'You didn''t select a choice.' } )
    else:
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('mysite.polls.views.results', args=(p.id,)))     

    return render_to_response('polls/vote.html', {'poll': p})
```

(this is maybe not exactly the same as in the tutorial, as it is my implementation, but the concept is the same)

At this part, it handles the request, and (possibly) inserts a record into the database.

Isn't this wrong? Shouldn't it be somewhere in the model? What happens in more complex scenarios? Won't the views get cluttered with lots of db-intensive code, and minimal presentation? Do larger applications have much longer (as in LOC) views?

Edit: [This FAQ entry doesn't answer my question](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/faq/general/#django-appears-to-be-a-mvc-framework-but-you-call-the-controller-the-view-and-the-view-the-template-how-come-you-don-t-use-the-standard-names)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is written in stone. In my mind:

- Views describe what data is to be presented (this is business specific, so it counts as business logic, but not business rules)
- Models describe data access and business rules (this is where I concentrate most of the domain specific rules about my data)
- Templates are the display layer, where the data selected in the views is formatted.

That said, because I rather like the philosophy of lean, simple templates; I sometimes have views doing a lot of masticating of the data to make the work of the templates simpler. I don't think of that as display code, but I've had some people telling me that it is.

About your example, you say:

> At this part, it handles the request, and (possibly) inserts a record into the database.

I don't understand what you mean...

That view is using the model to create a new record. First it asks for the model to update:

```
selected_choice = p.choice_set.get(id=request.POST['choice'])
```

Then it modifies the model and saves:

```
selected_choice.votes += 1
selected_choice.save()
```

All the logic about saving (including any overriden save() method) is at the model.

You have to have code to handle the actions on the models somewhere. Those are the views. They handle looking up data for display and they handle processing requests for modifications.

Comment: Thanks, this clarified many things. As for the record inserting, you are right. I messed up, because I also implemented an "add" view for the poll application, and I meant to include that snippet, but later changed my mind.

Answer (score 2):

You're misunderstanding what each of the components are for. In Django, the view is for *business logic*, which is exactly what the example demonstrates. Display logic belongs in the template.

That said, if you have very complex model-specific logic, you can certainly write a method on the model - but you'll still need to call it from the view, of course.

In any case, like all design patterns, MVC is simply a guide to how you structure your application, not a hard-and-fast rule.

Comment: So what about this: "In our interpretation of MVC, the “view” describes the data that gets presented to the user. It’s not necessarily how the data looks, but which data is presented. The view describes which data you see, not how you see it." ?

Comment: I mean, this is not really business logic.